# Context Menu displaying null value on RecyclerView Item

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a horizontal `recyclerview`in fragment and adding a context menu  on item click. I want to remove item from list which is working very fine. The problem is when menu pops up for first time it gives null value but when i click item for second time it works fine. I added a Toast , it shows value both the time.

> item position getter and setter declared globally

```
int selectedMemberPosition;
public int getSelectedMemberPosition() {
    return selectedMemberPosition;
}

public void setSelectedMemberPosition(int selectedMemberPosition) {
    this.selectedMemberPosition = selectedMemberPosition;
}
```

> ViewHolder Class

```
class SelectedMember_ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener{
        TextView nametxt;
        ImageView imgview;
        String nameToDelete;
        SelectedMember_ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nametxt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.set_meeting_selecteduserlist_textView);
            imgview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.set_meeting_selecteduserlist_imgview);
            itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo) {
            contextMenu.setHeaderTitle("Manage Member");
            contextMenu.add(0,view.getId(),0,"Remove "+ getNameToDelete());
        }

        String getNameToDelete() {
            return nameToDelete;
        }

        public void setNameToDelete(String nameToDelete) {
            this.nameToDelete = nameToDelete;
        }

    }
```

> onBindViewHolder method

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SelectedMember_ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final int i = position;
        final Selected_Member_Model model = selectedAdapteList.get(position);
        holder.nametxt.setText(model.getName());
        Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(model.getDp()).into(holder.imgview);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                holder.itemView.performLongClick();
                setSelectedMemberPosition(i);
                holder.setNameToDelete(model.getName()); //i think problem is here..this sets value null for first time
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), model.getName() + String.valueOf(getSelectedMemberPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

> onContextItemSelected method (global)

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int i = getSelectedMemberPosition();
    Selected_Member_Model model = selectedList.get(i);
    if(item.getTitle().equals("Remove "+model.getName())){
        selectedList.remove(i);
        selectedUserAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you correctly, but don't you want to call `performLongClick()` _after_ setting the position and name. That is, move `holder.itemView.performLongClick();` to the end of the `onClick()` method.

Comment: that was it. working fine now